# Windows 7 Black screen with curser

Tags: windows-7

After windows loads, instead of it showing the login screen it simply shows a black screen with a cursor.

I know why this error occurred. I was working on a clients computer and they had a password on it. So I attempted to use Spotmaou password removal tool. After that this is when it started happening. So i figure its something with the registry.

A re-install is out of the question because it is not a OEM key and they no longer have the key. Boot up repair does not work because its not a boot issue. Its a windows issue. And i've found out you cannot do a Windows Repair install on a computer you can't boot.. Which is stupid.

Also Safe mode does the same thing.

Comment: I hope you backed-up the SAM record for the windows installation; if you didn't, you can recreate it, but you'll lose all user account settings

Comment: nope.. Sure didn't. I've never had any trouble out of this disk.

Comment: check in C:\Windows\System32\config\; maybe that disk create a backup of the SAM file

Comment: There was a backup of it from around a year ago. I renamed the orginal sam file to sam.old and renamed "sam.bak" to "sam". But still the same results.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research i've found how to get the CD-Key from an offline computer. After doing this I was able to re-install the computer. Here are the steps how

Steps:

1. Load computer with UBCD4Win
2. Click Start
3. Click Programs
4. Click Info. and Diag. Tools
5. Click KeyfinderPE
6. Click Browser
7. Navigate to Hard Drive Windows Directory (example: C:\Windows)
8. Wait for program to load Hive
9. CD should now be displayed